# What does "crash" mean in this context?

Tags: slang

> Okay, 2 thoughts. Not that you asked, but...
>   1) You're going to **crash**, and it's okay when you do. This isn't a recovery. I did the same thing, it's part of the plan, usually, but you're not okay the way you think you are, so leave room for the bottom to fall out of this, make sure the right people are there to help, and you're next recovery will be a real one. You don't have to believe me.
>   2) don't give up on your step-daughter before you've talked to a lawyer. In many states (including mine) there are rights for a "defacto father" that can approximate an adoptive patent, particularly if get biodad isn't on the picture. It depends on the state, but it's worth asking.
>
> –[reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Divorce/comments/1suxk7/10_years_gone/ce1hhqp)

A guy gave out a rant and someone reply with the above message.
I am guessing it means an "emotional breakdown"?

Comment: I think "crash" here is a metaphor, saying one's life crashes is quite similar to saying a car or a plane crashes. A similar idiom is "crash and burn", which, when used figuratively, means: to fail spectacularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nearest meaning is *crash* after a drug high [[link]](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=crash&defid=176670)

> Hangover or other ill physical and psychological after effects as a result of a drug leaving your system and your body craving more. Specifically , this term refers to amphetamines, though it's often used to refer to other drugs as well.
>
> *The crash from the speed was so bad I couldn't move from the corner I was crying in for 3 hours, until I found my fifth of jim beam.*

In the linked post, the original poster says:

> From going from an emotional wreck with bugger all sleep to a happy single man with a huge life ahead of him in 3 days is surreal. How did I do it you may ask? I fucking sucked it up thats how. I focused on the facts not the emotional pain I had experienced all of 18 hours before. I put a call out on facebook to family and friends (my profile is private and only have true friends and family members) and I had a whole village come to my call!

This is essentially euphoric - like euphoric high similar to that from a drug. The answer says this will end soon, and end badly, with a very bad depressive feeling - "a crash", and the asker will need help of friends in making the actual recovery.

Comment: In America a "crash" is usually used to describe a sudden physical or emotional state following a period of an opposite state that is excessively long or intense. A crash after a drug high is a potent example. Also, we use "crash" to describe the physical reaction after going for multiple days without sleeping, or even just the energy drop that follows a "sugar rush".

Answer (score 1):

A crash in slang means that you will do whatever it takes to get someones attention or to become friends with that person(s)

IE: **p#1** "Aye If you go steal me that backpack in the mall, you could come to the kickback"

**p#2** " Alright"

**p**#**3**  " Damn you a crash"

Answer (score -1):

In English, if I asked someone if they were going to "crash here", it would be me asking them if they were going to stay here for awhile.   If someone was maybe going to get a hotel room or stay at your house after dinner, you could say, "are you going to crash here?" just to ask if they were going to spend the night.

Comment: I've updated the title to better reflect the question, and it may change your answer.